# Unable to resolve exception class in Multi catch

Tags: java, exception, multi-catch

I am creating a custom exception class using multicatch(Java 7 and above). This is the class that I have created. 
Please refer to the following code:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception{

public CustomException() {
    System.out.println("Default Constructor");
}
public CustomException(ArithmeticException e, int num){
    System.out.println("Divison by ZERO! is attempted!!! Not defined.");
}
public CustomException(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e, int num){
    System.out.println("Array Overflow!!!");
}
public CustomException(Exception e, int num){
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

and the above class is extended by the following class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ImplementCustomException extends CustomException {

public static void main(String[] args) throws CustomException {
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);){

        num = in.nextInt();
        int a = 35/num;

        int c[] = { 1 };
        c[42] = 99;
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException|ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

        throw new CustomException(e, num);
    }
}
}
```

Every time I am trying to run this, it calls the same constructor which is the one with "Exception".
Why is that happening?

However, if I replace the multi-catch syntax with the following code. It is working as expected.

```
catch(ArithmeticException ex){
        CustomException e = new CustomException(ex, num);
        throw e;
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        CustomException e = new CustomException(ex, num);
        throw e;
}
```

Please assist me with the possible changes that I can make in order to use multi catch and make it throw the required exception.

Comment: Don't get too accustomed to `!!!`. It is frowned upon by some people.

Comment: Side note: make sure that your custom exception is setup in a way so you don't loose information. What I mean: you create a custom exception upon hitting array index out of bounds ... but you are completely forgetting about that exception in your code. Meaning: if you just know that some array index out of bounds happened, but without its stack trace and message ... it will be very **hard** for you to debug problems later on.

Answer (score 4):

There is no common parent to `ArithmeticException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` other than `Exception`. In this one block

```
catch(ArithmeticException|ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    throw new CustomException(e, num);
}
```

`e` gets a static type, and this is <del>`Exception`</del>`RuntimeException`. With this, the `CustomException(Exception e, int num)` is called.

If you split them up, `e` has a more dedicated type.

Comment: @JornVernee Right, I corrected it. The basic statement remains the same, however.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is defined in [JLS Sec 14.20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) via this not-very-prominent sentence:

> The declared type of an exception parameter that denotes its type as a union with alternatives `D1 | D2 | ... | Dn` is `lub(D1, D2, ..., Dn)`.

`lub` means "least upper bound", defined in [JLS Sec 4.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4):

> The least upper bound, or "lub", of a set of reference types is a shared supertype that is more specific than any other shared supertype (that is, no other shared supertype is a subtype of the least upper bound).

In your case, the `lub` of `ArithmeticException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is `RuntimeException`, so the overload taking `Exception` as a parameter type is the most specific method that can be called.

Remember that it is the *compiler* that decides on the overload to be called: it is not decided at runtime.